# Register a new thread handlers like pthread_atfork or atexit

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, posix

I have a monitor/(watchdog kind of thread) thread which is used for query perf statistics of all threads. The thread query list of thread from /proc/self/tasks Once the list is created, I don't want to read /proc/self/tasks again unless new thread created or old thread exited. Other thread are not aware of this threads so they can't create pthread_key to get callback on exit or they can't add new entry in thread-queue on spawning.

I am looking for api like pthread_atfork or atexit for threads.

Comment: [`pthread_cleanup_push(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html)

Comment: Where does `atfork()` come from?

Comment: Join a thread to learn when it ended.

Comment: @alk unfortunately join-thread is blocking call, sorry about typo i meant atexit

Comment: pthread_cleanup_push is thread specific ,each thread has to register this function. @FilipeGonçalves

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: read /proc/self/tasks isn't that bad.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for api like atfork/pthread_atfork [...] for threads.

There is none.

You need to setup book-keeping for this yourself.

---

Write a wrapper thread function which is passed to each call of `pthread_create()` and have it set up the cleanup-pusher/-popper-stuff. As an argument to `pthread_create()` you pass a pointer to your "real" thread function which then gets called after the wrapper "called" `pthread_cleanup_push()`.

Comment: It doesn't. I was just noting that there exists a function called `pthread_atfork()`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: I know this, as well the OP seems to know, as however this question is about getting involved when threads are created/ended, s/he was asking for something alike `(pthread_)atfork()`/`atexit()`, just not for processes but for threads.

Comment: This is good solution. another way would be create pthread key and the destructor callback will called when thread exits. I was trying to design such way that threads won't be aware of this monitoring thread.